# datatables - preload first page of data while full dataset loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm looking for some advice from people who have done similar before:

I am using datatables.js to display a full table that is around 10,000 rows, and so it loads slowly (5-7 seconds) and gives "Script is not responding" popups - not a good user experience

I want the full set of data to be loaded to use the built-in Search filter as well as some custom filters, so ajax grabbing data on pagination, filter, etc is not desirable. (We like the snappiness, and the filtering may be pretty intense once data is loaded)

I've done some experimenting & think that perhaps:

-- load the first page with only a few records
-- at the same time, do a background ajax call on page load to build a second full table
-- finally, when data is there, replace the inital table with the ajax-built one
-- prolly need to rebind a few things

Before spending all the time that would take to set up and check, has anyone done that before or can offer different suggestions?

TIA,

Jeff

Comment: I'm afraid datatables doesn't ship with the feature you requested. based on my experience, when there's large dataset(3000+), the page loading would be pretty slow. you could try [server-side-processing](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), which tunes the performance a lot.

Comment: Server-side processing would actually end up DOSing your server when searching/filtering or clicking through next multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

As @yuwang says, this is how DataTables work. We have troubled with this ourselves - The problem is that DataTables is very slow on intializing, and about 4000 records seems to be the barrier in most browsers. In our apps, I have simply set a limit on 4000 - the DataTables view is mostly for convenience, and people can just make a more narrow search. Serverside processing is not a real solution.

Regarding "*load the first page with only a few records -- at the same time, do a background ajax call on page load to build a second full table*", try this :

**server.php, call with `brief=yes` if only the first 100 records should be loaded**

```
<table id="test-table">
<thead>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>date</th>
  <th>text</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?
function getColumn() {
    $row='<tr>';
    $row.='<td>'.rand(1, 100000).'</td>';
    $row.='<td>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mt_rand(1232055681, 1762855681)).'</td>';
    $row.='<td>'.str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqr').'</td>';
    $row.='</tr>';
    return $row;
}
$count=(isset($_GET['brief'])) ? 100 : 10000;
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    echo getColumn();
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**fully working example (copy and paste)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server.php?brief=yes',
        success : function(html) {
            $('#table-container').html(html);
            $("#test-table").DataTable();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'server.php',
                success : function(html) {
                    $('#table-container').html(html);
                    $("#test-table").DataTable();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="table-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Off course, in server.php the content of the records always changes, that will not be the case when you load records from a database (or whatever)